# Sigma Algebras, Dynkin Systems, and Pi Systems

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, logic

This book I'm reading contains the following claim:

> $(\Omega,A)$ is a sigma algebra iff it is a $\Pi$ system and a Dynkin System.

Proving the forward direction, its easy to show that if $(\Omega,A)$ is a sigma algebra then it is a Dynkin System.

However, its not true though that every sigma algebra is a $\Pi$ system. For instance if: $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$ and $A = \{ \emptyset, \{1\},\{3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}$}. Evidently $\{2,3\}\cap \{1,2\} \notin A$.

Is the forward direction true then?

Comment: $\sigma$-algebras must be closed under countable intersection. So $A$ is not a $\sigma$-agebra. Whether this fact is part of your definition or it follows immediately from it by applying De Morgan, I can't quite tell.

Comment: What are $\Pi$ and Dynkin systems?

Comment: @Berci [$\pi$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system) and [Dynkin system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system).

Comment: Saucy -- you can add that as an answer if you wish